# Missing autoconf macro doesn't throw an error, but ./configure does

Tags: gcc, makefile, configure, autoconf

How can I make autogen.sh error if `AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG` is missing?

I could just wget the .m4 file into the source tree and include it, is that a better option than giving an error?

Here are the details:

I just added `AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG(...)` to my configure.ac and ran `./autogen.sh`, which succeeded.

Because `autoconf-archive` wasn't installed, `./configure` gave this error:

`./configure: 5358: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")`

the ./configure line at 5358 looks like this below because the macro didn't exist, so bourne shell died with the error above.

`AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG(-fcx-fortran-rules, CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -fcx-fortran-rules")`

Comment: `autogen.sh` is not standardized nor even universal, so it's hard to speak to why the particular `autogen.sh` you're looking at produces the behavior you describe.  Certainly Autoconf does produce warnings for some cases where it thinks it may have seen a reference to an undefined macro.

Comment: @JohnBollinger  what is the "proper" way to check configure.ac for errors?

Comment: The standard way to do what `autogen.sh` scripts typically do is to use the `autoreconf` command.  But what `autogen.sh` scripts typically do is *not* check `configure.ac` for errors, except incidentally.  For `configure.ac` specifically, you can also run `autoconf` directly, maybe as `autoconf -W all -f` to get the maximum warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a rule, when I use macros in `configure.ac` whose name begins with neither `AC_` nor `AM_`, I make sure that autoconf treats those macro names occuring in the generated `configure` file as an error.

In your case, that would be

```
m4_pattern_forbid([AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG])dnl
AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG([...what...], [...ever...])
AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG([...and...], [...more...])
```